# Boot from USB: BIOS proceed to Grub 2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb

Using Grub 2 back in the days, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a dual-boot way with my existing Windows 7 installation. However, I wish to reformat my drive completely and install only Ubuntu on it - without any other partitions at all.

However, having burned an image of Ubuntu onto a USB stick with `unetbootin`, I cannot seem to boot from this USB. In my boot option in BIOS, I can pick the USB stick correctly, but I'm not prompted to do anything - the sequence just leads me to Grub 2, where I can either boot Ubuntu 14.04 or Windows 7. Nothing else.

How do I format everything, and install a new partition of Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: If this is your usual boot menu then it's looks like it's not booting from your USB stick. Have you tried using UNetbootin from both systems? IMO it works better from Windows. If it's booting from USB then you should see large blue menu covering half of your screen. Did you use ISO file in UNetbootin?

Comment: My windows 7 partition is broken, I only have the option of using Ubuntu for this purpose

Comment: Can you use a CD/DVD for boot? Because this is the best option. And… one more thing. Does your PC use BIOS to boot? Or is it using UEFI?

Comment: It is using the LEGACY+UEFI mode. No, I have no CD's to use as of now.

Comment: Do you have another/old computer to test your USB stick? If you do then try it and tell us if it worked. And we will try to help you solve your problem.

Comment: I'm completely sure the USB stick is fine - I just attempted with startup disk creator as well, and it looks just normal. Bootloader etc. installed on it also. I'm suspecting something is up with grub2? I don't know. Seems like a complicated process to format the two partitions and install this one solely?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33752/discussion-between-pvc-and-cbll).

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Change boot mode from "UEFI+LEGACY" to "UEFI ONLY"

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)